# Intellij condition always false when reached warning

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the below code,

I have an enum and a BigInteger variable. Please find the if condition used

```
public enum EnumCode {
        Open,
        Closed,
        None
    }

private boolean TEST(final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext, final BigInteger amount, final EnumCode enumCode) {
    if (enumCode == EnumCode.Closed && null == amount) {
        //error message1
        return false;
    }

    if (enumCode != EnumCode.Closed && null != amount) {
        //error message2
        return false;
    }

    if (null == enumCode && null != amount) { //**Condition is always false when reached**
        //error message3
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How to fix the warning?

Comment: "How to fix the warning?" Remove that if statement.

Comment: `enumCode != EnumCode.Closed` is true if `enumCode == null`. 2nd if condition includes the 3rd if condition

Comment: @jhamon: Thanks. Looks like I made a very silly mistake

Comment: When you reach the 3rd if condition, amount won't be equal to null so null!= amount would result false. Secondly, null == enumCode will also result to false because  you have already verified it in the second if statement. In your second if statement, when saying, null!= EnumCode.Closed; the [possible values for the condition to be true includes  {null, open,none}. This means you don't need to check it again null == enumCode because it will be false.  As per the Boolean algebra, false && false is false. You simply remove the third if, because they are included in your previous if.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (enumCode == EnumCode.Closed && null == amount) {
    return false;
}

if (enumCode != EnumCode.Closed && null != amount) {
    return false;
}
```

If `enumCode == null`, then `enumCode != EnumCode.Closed`. As such, this:

```
if (null == enumCode && null != amount) {
    return false;
}
```

would never be true without the previous condition being true.

To fix this, remove the final if statement, as it is redundant.

---

As an aside, you can write it with just one if statement:

```
if ((enumCode == EnumCode.Closed) == (null == amount)) {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `enumCode`is `null`, the condition `enumCode != EnumCode.Closed` is true.
So the 2nd `if`condition includes the 3rd one.

You should check if it's differents from `EnumCode.Closed` and if it's not null.

```
if (enumCode == EnumCode.Closed && null == amount) {
    return false;
}

if (enumCode != null && enumCode != EnumCode.Closed && null != amount) {
    return false;
}

if (null == enumCode && null != amount) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically explained, once you reach the 3rd if condition, the variable amount won't be equal to null so *null!= amount* would result *false*. Secondly, *null == enumCode* will also result to *false* because  you have already verified it in the second *if statement*. Moreover, in your *second if statement*, when saying, *null!= EnumCode.Closed;* the possible values for the condition to be true includes  *{null, open,none}*. This means you don't need to check it again with *null == enumCode* because it will be false anyways. As per the Boolean algebra, *false && false is false*. To solve the problem, you simply remove the third if, because they are included in your previous if.

```
public enum EnumCode {
        Open,
        Closed,
        None
    }

private boolean TEST(final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext, final BigInteger amount, final EnumCode enumCode) {
    if (enumCode == EnumCode.Closed && null == amount) {
        //error message1
        return false;
    }

    if (enumCode != EnumCode.Closed && null != amount) {
        //error message2
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```